# Grand Total in Summary Band using Delphi Report Builder

Tags: delphi

I have two variables in the detail tab using Delphi report builder and the running totals are correct.  It is getting its data from two sets of the client data sets within the Delphi code.

Now I need to get the grand total of the total that comes from the variables in the details band to calculate in the summary band.  How would I go about doing this?  Would I declare a global variable and set that? and if yes then how would I use that global variable with two different totals?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*(I assume you mean Digital Metaphor's Report Builder - not sure if that's bundled with Delphi now or not...)*

To create your grand totals:

Just create a summary band in the designer: `Report->Summary`, and put two `DBCalc` components in there. Assign their data fields to the fields you want to summarize as grand totals. This works because the `DBCalc` component is context aware - it knows what sort of band it lives in: If it's in a group footer, it aggregates for the group, if it's in the report summary section, it aggregates for the whole report.

**Important:** Consider if you need to summarize your subtotals, or directly aggregate all the data in the report. Depending on the data types and how you handle rounding, truncating, etc, there could be a difference between the two that causes you to come up with results that you aren't expecting.

BTW, I'm not sure why you're referring to `variables` - you should use `DBCalc` components for all your summations - they work automatically and are very easy to use, provided you put them in the correct band and feed them the correct data.

*(All this is readily available in the Report Builder docs: [**Report Builder - Documentation | Developer's Guide**](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/download/developers_guide.html), which is probably why this question was downvoted. You are supposed to do some preliminary research before posting a question here. )*